# Python script to execute a C program at particular time interval

Tags: python, c

I have a .c file and this file has to be executed only at a particular time interval say 9pm.
So, please let me know if there is any possibility of achieving this via python scripting.

Comment: Please see my updated answer that covers the scheduling part of the question.

Comment: Updated answer again to show how to schedule using either cron or python.  Hope this will do it for you!  Please "Accept" if it solves your problem completely, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `subprocess` module in the standard python library.  Something like:

```
from subprocess import call
```

Then when you want to issue your command:

```
call(["yourprogramname", "argument1"])
```

Of course, you need to get your C program into an executable form and make it executable on your platform.  This will allow you to decide when to run the program under control of python (hour 21=9pm):

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

x=datetime.today()
y=x.replace(day=x.day+1, hour=21, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t=y-x

secs=delta_t.seconds+1

def runmycommand():
    <your call command here>
    #...

t = Timer(secs, runmycommand)
t.start()
```

However, if you're on a on a unix/linux platform, you can make it run on a schedule by adding it to `crontab`:

```
0,14,29,44 * * * * /yourprogramlocation/yourprogramname
```

To learn how to schedule with `cron` use the `man cron` command or see [a tutorial like this one.](https://www.howtogeek.com/101288/how-to-schedule-tasks-on-linux-an-introduction-to-crontab-files/)

Answer (score 0):

What previous answers miss is your question about how to trigger at a specific time, e.g. 9pm.

You can use cron for this. It's a *nix utility that executes arbitrary commands on a time schedule you specify.

You could set cron to run your C program directly, or to launch a Python wrapper that then starts your C executable.

To get started: type `crontab -e` and follow the examples.