# How to schedule a periodic task in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, scheduled-tasks

How can I schedule a periodic task in python without blocking?

Here is a simple situation. Assume this ticket variable becomes invalid after 2 hours. So I need to fetch it from a serve.

```
ticket = 1 # It expires every 2 hours

def process_using_ticket(): # This function is called using a get request from flask server 
    print('hello', ticket)
```

How can I reset to 1 every two hours without blocking?

One way could be to start a thread and sleep for 2 hours and then reset the variable but I am wondering if there are better alternatives.

**Note: Everything runs in a docker.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a use case for [`cron`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab), a simple utility found on all linux machines to schedule periodic tasks. A simple **cron** task could be created like:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Within the cron, make an entry

```
0 */2 * * *  /home/username/ticket_script.py
```

Make sure that your script has executable permissions. In case you are printing something in your script, make the cron entry to redirect its ouput like

```
0 */2 * * *  /home/username/ticket_script.py >> /home/username/ticket_script_runs.log
```

---

For gotchas on running this in Docker, you can go through this thread ->  https://forums.docker.com/t/cronjobs-in-docker-container/2618/5 which says:

> Most Docker containers only run the binary you specify (in this case /bin/bash), so there is no cron daemon running to trigger these jobs.
>
> There are a number of ways you can deal with this - for small adhoc things, you can add the cron entry to your host's crontab, and trigger the job in the container using docker exec containername ...
>
> You can replace the container entrypoint with a shell script that starts the cron, or if you have a need for several services, use something like supervisord to manage them.
>
> And if you're going all in, you can make a cron container which you can then use to kick off tasks using docker exec.

---

The other approach is what you already have - go to sleep for 2 hours, or maintain a `time_last_read` timestamp, keep evaluating if its been 2 hours since your last read (`time_now - time_last_read >= 2_HOURS`), and re-read the value into memory once the condition is True and reset `time_last_read`.

Comment: Just went with the simple checking time method instead of cron.

Comment: @utengr Happy to help. I've added Docker tag to the question, since it has heavily influenced the choice of solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a function with `time.sleep(7200000)`. Like so:

```
import time

ticket = 1

def main_loop():
    while True:
        time.sleep(7200000)
        ticket = 1

def process_using_ticket():
    print('hello', ticket) 
main_loop()
```