# python schedule module to periodically run a function

Tags: python, schedule

Goal: run a function every day at a randomized time between two times.

So, I wrote this function to randomly generate a time (please offer feedback on how to streamline. Couldn't find this in an existing package - it MUST already exist...)

```
def gen_rand_time(low, high):
    hour = np.random.randint(low, high)
    minute = np.random.randint(1,59)
    if minute < 10:
        time = str(hour)+':'+str(0)+str(minute)
        return time
    else:
        time = str(hour) + ':' + str(minute)
        return time
```

Next I define the function I would like to run. Keeping it nice and simple.

```
def test(a):
    print('TEST: ' + str(a))
```

Now I want to run this runction on a periodic basis. I use the schedule package.

```
def run_bot():
    time1 = str(gen_rand_time(18,19))
    print(time1)
    schedule.every(1).days.at(time1).do(test('TEST WORKED'))
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
run_bot()
```

when I run run_bot() and put in a time in the immediate future (say, 1 minute into the future), the test() function returns "TEST: TEST WORKED" without waiting for the specified random time.

Comment: I might miss something, but do you actually execute run_bot function?

Comment: Yeah, I do in my script. Forgot it off on the post here accidentally. I edited it accordingly

Comment: Missing `:` after `def run_bot()`. What is the output of print(time1)?

Comment: "the function returns a result"... Which function returns which result? It would be good if you were more thorough in describing your case.

Comment: OK, I have updated the post. The problem is not with the random time that is generated but is with the scheduling of the test() function. In other words, the test() function is not running at the time that is specified. It runs immediately. Hopefully that is more clear.

Comment: What I get with your script is
  File "<string>", line 9, in gen_rand_time
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1264, in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:14492)
ValueError: low >= high
It seems you cannot use the same number for both parameters... did you manage to do that?

Comment: Ok, it seems you did not actually try what was posted... that is usually not recommended. Minor differences might mislead people trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try `... do(test,'TEST WORKED')`
instead of `... do(test('TEST WORKED'))`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python#comment74880397_16786600).

Besides, it seems that you cannot use the same value for `low` and `high` (I wonder if you actually tried what you posted).

Comment: That was intentional because I was trying to generate a "random" time in the hour of when I was testing (which was 6pm local)