# call a method at a certain time (python)

Tags: python, timer

What is the proper way to call a method at a certain time (certain time here is a parameter)?

I need the timer, but is it necessary to represent incoming time and `time.now()` in seconds to get and to use the difference between them?

The code:

```
import datetime, time
import threading
from threading import Timer

def doItThen():
    print ("did it")

def launchTimer(dateAndTime):
    dateTimeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
    t = threading.Timer((dateAndTime-dateTimeNow).seconds, doItThen)
    t.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    launchTimer(datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 21, 8, 27, 51))
```

the result:

> did it

(works)

but what are the risks in using this approach? im not good in testing or predicting the weeknesses

Comment: Try the method you propose and edit your post to include the result

Comment: I am thinking about using this kind of the routine: t1 = datetime (2010, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) // t2 = datetime.now() // t = threading.Timer((t1-t2).seconds, doItThen) // t.start() ... don't know if it's a proper way to do it

Comment: Try it, and then edit your post to include the result.

Comment: Done. But what are the risks in using this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the module [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) might be what you are looking for.

[How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python)

```
import schedule
import time 
def job(): 
    print("I'm working...")     

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job) 
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job) 
while 1: 
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out `scheduler.enterabs` from Python's [Sched lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html).

The `enterabs` function allows you to set a specific time to call a function.  Here's a [direct link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler.enterabs).

The basic syntax is as follows:

```
scheduler.enterabs(time, priority, action, argument=(), kwargs={})
```

Answer (score 0):

use [python schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule)

> schedule.every().day.at("10:10").do(job)

Comment: I need to call a method at a random time. It's not periodic or predictable.

Comment: explaint what exactly you are going to do by this. also you can make a random timestamps and pu it in a list like [1518942118,1518942125,...] then run it with schedule