# Compare current time to time in Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, scheduled-tasks

I have a program I already wrote to send text messages to a client as a demo, no actual text were sent.  Now I need the program to send the texts when it is a specific time of day every day.  I have made an excel file with all my clients names, when, they need to be texted and all the other essential information I need to run each of my programs.  I'm trying to use a conditional statement that basically says if the current time matches the date in column "Med Time 1", then run the first definition I have which will send the text to start the conversation. I'm having syntax error every time I try anything. This is what I have so far without all the coding for the program I will run since I can't get past the conditional statement. I tried adding a column in the Excel file with the "Current date".  That has not worked either.  I've been stumped for two weeks.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

#Assign spreadsheet filename
file = 'Uganda_Data.xlsx'

#Load spreadsheet
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)

#Parse the first sheet
df = xl.parse('Sheet1')

# Medication
if datetime.datetime.now() == df[['Current date','Med Time 1']]
```

Comment: Are you asking *how to send text messages* **or** *how run code at a scheduled time* **or** *how to retrieve times from Excel with Python*??

Comment: run a task at a specific time?  I have several clients on a database in excel.  Each person has a specific time that they are to be contacted to start my program, which is one of the columns in the excel file. I need to be able to translate from the excel file column to something I can compare the current either datetime.datetime.now() or datetime,datetime.now().time()

Comment: or some other way to let my programs definition to know to run. currently it's in demo mode, so I have a button that I push in tkinter to start the program.  I need it to be a working system now and not a demo.

Comment: How to schedule jobs in Python: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786600/8112776](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786600/)

Comment: Hey @ElizabethBirdRock, where are you running this code? Will it be run locally on your machine, or is it going to be on a server somewhere?

Comment: excuse me, I was told to make a demo first, until we got our grant money.  Now I have to make a working product. I only asked for help because I've been stuck for two weeks with error after error.  I didn't expect someone else to do my project for me.  I just needed help figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm running it on my computer, but eventually I'm hoping it will be on a server.

Answer (score 0):

The class `datetime.datetime.now()` returns a object containing all the information from the date (year,month,day,hour,minute,second,microsecond).

Suppose that "now" is 3/21/2018 6:10 PM and you call (note the precision of seconds and microseconds):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 21, 18, 10, 05, 335514)
```

And you wrote and saved an excel file like this at the same time (using the function `=now()` for Currente Date):

```
User    Current Date    Med Time 1
user 1  3/21/18 6:00 AM 3/21/18 17:29 AM
user 2  3/21/18 6:00 AM 4/21/18 4:00 AM
user 3  3/21/18 6:00 AM 4/5/18 5:00 PM
```

Now you load the file using pandas.read_excel() (instead pandas.ExcelFile).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import datetime

>>> df = pd.read_excel('Uganda_Data.xlsx')
>>> df
     User        Current Date          Med Time 1
0  user 1 2018-03-21 06:00:00 2018-03-21 18:10:05
1  user 2 2018-03-21 06:00:00 2018-04-21 04:00:00
2  user 3 2018-03-21 06:00:00 2018-04-05 17:00:00
```

Note that `Med Time 1` for `user 1` is another type of object (is **Timestamp** but not **Datetime.Datetime**)

```
>>> df['Med Time 1'][0]
Timestamp('2018-03-21 18:10:05')
```

Note that `Current Date` at `df` is the date\time at the time you save the excel file, and will never be equals to the time you call `datetime.datetime.now()`.

So, you should convert dates, e.g. using

```
>>> pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime.now())
Timestamp('2018-03-21 18:40:42.639488')
```

### Code Suggestion

```
import pandas as pd

#Assign spreadsheet filename
file = 'Uganda_Data.xlsx'

#Load spreadsheet
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)

#Parse the first sheet
df = xl.parse('Sheet1')

# Filter users that are on time to take the medicine
df_now = df[df['Med Time 1'] == pd.Timestamp.now()]

# Do something...
for line in df_now:
    print("Call the user {}".format(df['Users']))
    ...
```

Note: be careful about what is in `Med Time 1`. My suggestion is that you keep time as **hour:minute** without seconds and microseconds. You should code (when and if necessary):

```
df['Med Time 1'].map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```