# How to set up a Cron Job in Python, using Putty (OS is Linaro)

Tags: python, cron, directory

I'm trying to set up a Cron Job on someone else's code to run on an ASUS Tinkerboard

It's currently a simple script that just connects to a device within range (that works)

I've used `crontab -e` to open up my file, and all I've put in is:

```
0 * * * * * ~Projects/Tinker/example.py
```

I want it to run every hour on the hour, but it isn't doing so.
I think I'm not setting up my directories correctly. On the command window, the only thing I see for directories is:

```
name@linaro-alip ~/Projects/Tinker/example.py
```

How can I fix this so that my program will run every hour?

Comment: I don't know anything about that environment, but my first suggestion is  to use the explicit path to the executable without the tilde.

Comment: I've got the explicit path and I added it in. still not working

Comment: The entry of your crontab is missing a slash before "Projects". So it should read ~/Projects.... instead of ~Projects. Just as a tipp - before I add something as a cronjob, I always copy - paste it in the shell and try whether it works beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use Putty? If not, see this answer - [How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python).

It uses a library called schedule. I'm using it myself to delete files from a directory every morning.

basically you will `pip install schedule', and then run your script with something like:

```
import schedule 
def job():
    #Whatever the function does

schedule.every().hour.do(job)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does have to be in Putty, I tried what you said and it isn't working. I get the error "schedule is not defined" even after running the install

I put import schedule in my script but it says "no module named schedule"

Comment: After installing "schedule" you have to import it before you use it in the script.

Comment: Sorry, edited answer to include import statement. It should work now