# How to run a python function every day at specific time

Tags: python

I am trying to run a specific function every day at 18:00, I wrote the folwing code to do that but it did nothing

```
    today = datetime.today()
    nextDay = (today + timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=18, minute=0, second=0)
    delta_time = nextDay - today
    secs = delta_time.seconds + 1
    timer = Timer(secs, self.send_officer_report(".send officer report --ad " + today.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"), today.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")))
    timer.start()
```

I do not want to use `cron`, I want my script to be OS independent

Comment: You should use server side applications like Supervisor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786600/9308420

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`cron` and related applications are the basic way to do this. With your approach, you have to keep the Python interpreter running  24/7, and if it crashes, all your times are off.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to use `cron`, I want my script to be OS independent

Comment: So your  question may be a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python