# Exporting CSV file into a specific path and Creating an automated code that runs daily

Tags: python

I am a novice at python and I am trying to create my first automated code in jupyter notebooks that will export my data pull from SQL server to a specific path and this code needs to run daily. 
My questions:
1- It needs to export the CSV file to a specific folder, don't know how to do that
2- I need the code to run by itself on a daily basis

I am stuck, Any help is appreciated.

I have connected to the sql server and successfully pull the report and write a CSV file.

```
import smtplib
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql

server = 'example server'
db = 'ExternalUser'

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=example server;'
                      'Database=ExternalUser;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("my SQL query")

col_headers = [ i[0] for i in cursor.description ]
rows = [ list(i) for i in cursor.fetchall()]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=col_headers)
df.to_csv("Test v2.csv", header = True, index=False)
```

Comment: passing in the location as the filename will create the csv file at a particular location.. 
Just make sure the directory exists..

Comment: Running it everyday will be determined by your os. This is not something the python will handle. In linux you would use crontab, in Windows it's the task scheduler.

Comment: to run it daily just search up a scheduler program for python .. 
Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python

Comment: Please restrict your questions to one task first. Also, be specific with the problems you have. When asking about code, also extract a [mcve] first. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: if you SO is linux ..just set your scheduler in /etc/crontab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For needing to export the csv too a certain folder: It depends where/how you run the script. If you run the script in the folder you want the csv file saved then your current `df.to_csv('filename.csv')` would work great, or add a path 'Test_dir/filename.csv'. Otherwise you could use a library like `shutil` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) that will then move the .csv file to a given folder.

For running the code on a daily basis, you could do this locally on your machine (https://medium.com/@thabo_65610/three-ways-to-automate-python-via-jupyter-notebook-d14aaa78de9). Or you could look into configuring a cronjob.

Comment: Thank you. I got the script to work now thanks to your comment.

Comment: @KamS Mind giving this answer a upvote or a checkmark? Glad you got your script to start working! Congrats!

Comment: That was the first thing i tried to do... but my account doesn't have enough 'reputation' and it doesn't show it on the site.

Comment: @KamS oh no worries! Happy Coding!

Comment: William it does let me give you a check Mark. Thanks for your help bud