# How good/bad is using time.sleep(secs) in python to schedule a periodic task of calling a function?

Tags: python, timer

```
import schedule 
import time 
def check(num): 
 if num == 1: 
  print('abc'); 
  check(2)
 else: 
  schedule.every(1).minute.do(check, num = 1); 
  while True:
   schedule.run_pending() 
   time.sleep(1); 
check(1);
```

This is the code i have been using, please suggest

Comment: use a cron job (on unix)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python)

Comment: @Javide - Like I mentioned in the comments, i have tried this. And it doesn't work for me for some weird reason.  The function runs 10(mins)*60(secs) times for me after the 10mins time is elapsed. It gets into a maximum recursive loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but this approach is simple:

```py
def function():
#
# your function here
#

while True:
    function()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Or you can use async to make python not wait for the end of the function to continue

Comment: @Nathan- Using a time.sleep() in a while loop without a scheduler, how does it affect the memory allocation, if the program is made to run for the whole day? Also, time.sleep(), does it make the program stop and restart once the time lapses?