# Trouble understanding schedule

Tags: python, schedule

I'm trying to get my head around schedule. I've looked at [How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python) and have altered the code but cannot figure out why

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I\'m doing the job")

schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

is giving me.

```
I'm doing the job
I'm doing the job
I'm working...
I'm working...
I'm doing the job
I'm working!
I'm working...
I'm working...
I'm working...
I'm working!
I'm working!
I'm working...
```

Comment: Where are the `I'm working...` and `I'm working!` messages coming from?  It seems like you haven't shown us all the code.

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon that is the crux of it. That is my entire code. Could there be some other issue?

Comment: The code in the linked post has messages like that.  Do you have a copy of that program still running in the background?