# How can i start this function every day (Python3 - Schedule)

Tags: python-3.x, schedule

This is my actually script with chromedriver: [Schedule part 1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpeWk.png)

And this is end script: [Schedule part 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQhGX.png)

I need to run this program every day and specific time.. like wednesday at 12:00.. i tryed but the program don't start.. 0 errors.

Comment: Please post relevant code in the question itself, rather than giving screenshots of it. The code that you post should be as close to a [mcve] as possible.

Comment: Following the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786600/11527436), I'd assume that you should not put the schedule into the function that you want to call.