# Can you clear a SQL database at a specific time

Tags: python, sql, database

I am creating a parking booking system in python.

The last time slot ends at 3PM, I want to do something where I clear the whole SQL database at 3PM so that the bookings don't need to be manually deleted.

is there any way of doing this in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python)

Comment: What RDBMS? MySQL has an Event Scheduler, you can run a query at the same time each day.

Comment: Have you considered using timestamps and querying for records in the current day? That way you don't necessarily need to delete anything.