# How do I make my if statement run only once in while loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a notifier at an exact time
Here's the code:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

toaster = ToastNotifier()

while True:
    if now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "1:23 PM":
        toaster.show_toast("Bot:","It's 1:23 PM")
    elif now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "4:43 PM":
        toaster.show_toast("Bot:","It's 4:43 PM")
    elif now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "7:32 PM":
        toaster.show_toast("Bot:","It's 7:32 PM")
    elif now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "8:44 PM":
        toaster.show_toast("Bot:","It's 8:44 PM")
    elif now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "6:02 AM":
        toaster.show_toast("Bot:","It's 6:02 AM")
```

But when I run the code yesterday, the notification shows forever, and when I close it, it shows again. Please help me fix this and thank you!

Comment: If you want to execute the ```if...elif...else``` only once, why use a ```while``` loop? You can add ```break``` after ```if``` statement

Comment: what is the purpose of the while loop?

Comment: I want it to be automatic, I don't want to run the code at the specific time, I want to run the code once, and the rest will be automatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import schedule
import time
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
toaster = ToastNotifier()

def job():
    toaster.show_toast("Bot: It's 10:30 PM")

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job) #change time 10:30 to you want

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: is the schedule 24 hour format? because I don't understand the .at("10:30") is it morning or night?

Comment: yes, if you want night edit 22:30

Answer (score 1):

You can add `break` at the end of your `if-block`

```
while True:
    if now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "1:23 PM":
        toaster.show_toast("Bot:","It's 1:23 PM")
        break
    elif now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "4:43 PM":
        toaster.show_toast("Bot:","It's 4:43 PM")
        break
    elif now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "7:32 PM":
        toaster.show_toast("Bot:","It's 7:32 PM")
        break
    elif now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "8:44 PM":
        toaster.show_toast("Bot:","It's 8:44 PM")
        break
    elif now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "6:02 AM":
        toaster.show_toast("Bot:","It's 6:02 AM")
        break
```

Comment: wouldn't it stop my while loop from running?

Comment: @BlueDuck. Yes, it would stop

Comment: Well I want it to continue so when it's 4 pm it shows a notification again.

Comment: @BlueDuck - Don't you want your while-loop to stop after it matches an if/else statement? Also, `now = datetime.now()` should be inside the `while` if you want to re-evaluate it each time.

Comment: I wanted to make it like when it's 10 am it shows notification once and then the script waits until it's 11 am and shows notification again and then wait until it's 12 am and run the code again, I want this script to be looped forever

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to run only once, you don't needs to use loop
want to check state using conditional statement or add break after if state

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

toaster = ToastNotifier()

if now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "1:23 PM":
    toaster.show_toast("Bot:", "It's 1:23 PM")
elif now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "4:43 PM":
    toaster.show_toast("Bot:", "It's 4:43 PM")
elif now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "7:32 PM":
    toaster.show_toast("Bot:", "It's 7:32 PM")
elif now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "8:44 PM":
    toaster.show_toast("Bot:", "It's 8:44 PM")
elif now.strftime('%I:%M %p') == "6:02 AM":
    toaster.show_toast("Bot:", "It's 6:02 AM")
```

Comment: but that wouldn't work, it will only work when I run the code at the specific time. I want it to be automatic and I need to run the code once not running the code when it's 1:23 pm and so on

Comment: ahh, check this schedule library   

https://pypi.org/project/schedule/

it makes easy to run automatically at time you want

Comment: Can you code it out for me, I don't know how to use it @Seonghun

Answer (score 0):

For that end you would be better using the schedule package! Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786600/10048135)
Schedule runs like a clock timer (cron) you set the alarm time and it runs following the configuration... You could configure it to run everyday at a specific time or multiple times.

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I don't know how to use this library, can you code it out for me please? I'm so sorry.

Comment: Improved the answer with the code example: this now run the job every day at 10:30... You can change the time to whatever you want. And edit the job to run what you want at the time specified.