# How to make timeout callback funtion in rabbit ioloop

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

I need to make a function to be executed every n seconds. I have found a `call_later` method, but the problem is it executes only once:

```
self._connection.ioloop.call_later(self.timeout, self.callback)
```

How do I properly make a timeout function? Is there any way to use only pika ioloop methods for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a Cron like scheduler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python)

Comment: how about calling `call_later` from inside `callback` so that everytime it's called, you schedule another one for the future?